# Java:Arithmetic

Tags: java, math

Do you see anything wrong in this code? in thosen't work well it returns a NaN.

```
public class Method2 extends GUIct1
{
double x=0,y=0;


void settype1 (double conv1)
{
x = conv1;
}

void settype2 (double conv2)
{
y = conv2;
}

double conversion ( double amount)
{


double converted = (amount*y)/x;
    return converted;
}

}
```

Way it is used an i already changed the set part

```
Method2 convert = new Method2(); \\ method is called
```

.....

```
convert.settype1(j);
```

.....

```
convert.settype2(k);
```

.....

```
double x = convert.conversion(i);
System.out.println(x);
```

Comment: Your get methods should be named set.

Comment: the code snippet is incomplete. please update it.

Comment: You're initializing `x` with 0 in a class that divides by `x` - what did you expect to happen? It's like leaving fuel and matches in the wood and hoping nobody uses them together ;)

Comment: On which function?  On conversion?  If you don't set x to something other than zero you're going to get a divide by zero error.

Answer (score 7):

Well, the fact that you've got methods which *set* variables called `get`-something is pretty obviously not a good idea, and there's no indentation... but it should *work*. But then, you haven't shown how you're using it. Perhaps you're not actually called the setter methods?

Here's an example of the same code but with different names, and a sample of using it:

```
class Converter
{
    double multiplier = 0;
    double divisor = 0;


    void setMultiplier(double multiplier)
    {
        this.multiplier = multiplier;
    }

    void setDivisor(double divisor)
    {
        this.divisor = divisor;
    }

    double convert(double amount)
    {
        return (amount * multiplier) / divisor;
    }
}

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Converter converter = new Converter();
        converter.setMultiplier(3.5);
        converter.setDivisor(8.5);
        System.out.println(converter.convert(2)); // Prints 0.8235294117647058
    }
}
```

Personally I'd probably make the variables final and set them in the constructor, but that's another matter...

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you ever call gettype1 or gettype2 so the x/y is 0/0 resulting in NaN

Comment: Well we haven't seen any code which calls `conversion` either, so we can't really tell what's going on...

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when x=0. Division by zero is not defined. Print out x and y before you start to calculate to see whetther they are not zero.

Comment: I tried that and no till that point everything is working fine i guess